# How does Fedex calculate Handling rates in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, fedex

I am using a fedex shipping method in my magento website I want to add more 30% on my shipping charges which will be my margin. IS it possible using handling charges section in shipping methodd setting of magento. How Fedex calculate that handling charges. please explain me and give correct suggestion. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1. Go to: Fedex Developer Resource Center and create developer’s account.

Step 2. When you create developer’s account go to Developer Resource Center and click on top navigation FedeEx Web Services -> FedeEx Web Services for Shipping.
 Now, you will see the link Develop & Test Your Application (about testing, obtain developer test key) click on it. Then you only have to send request for test environment, you can see the link “Obtain Developer Test Key” click on it and fill the form. After sending form with data, you will receive email message from FedEx with all required data for testing FedEx shipping method.

Comment: Thanks Trixie But I know that how to get the test credentials of Fedex but I want to know that what is handling charges this charges go to seller account or in fedex account.